# Sum of conditions in conditional probablity

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-process

I'm taking a class on Markov Processes and my professor claimed that we can sum up $P(A|X_{1}=x_{1},X_{2}=x_{2})$ over all possible $x_{2}$ and thus eliminate term $X_{2}$. I assume he meant that $$
\sum_{x_{2} \in I}\mathbb{P}(A|X_{1}=x_{1},X_{2}=x_{2}) = P(A|X_{1} = x_{1})
$$ where $I$ is a countable state space. What he claimed doesn't seem to be true in my opinion, so any ideas on what he could possibly mean?

P.S. I'm sorry that I forgot when this occurred exactly, but I will edit the post if I find out. I did look through posts but did not really find anything that directly answers my question

Comment: $$\begin{align}
 \sum_{x_{2} \in I}\left(\mathbb{P}(X_2 =x_2)\cdot\mathbb{P}(A|X_{1}=x_{1},X_{2}=x_{2})\right) = \mathbb{P}(A|X_{1} = x_{1}) 
\end{align}$$

Comment: @NN2 Thank you. That might be what he meant.